# MySQL SELECT all ids and child ids in a JSON array

Tags: mysql, json, select

I'm having a data col which contains some records as json arrays, example

```
[
  {
    "id": 4065,
    "pageTitle": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "children": [
        {
        "id": 4067,
        "pageTitle": "Foo",
      },
      {
        "id": 4072,
        "pageTitle": "Bar",
      }
  },
  {
    "id": 4070,
    "pageTitle": "Another Lorem Ipsum",
    "children": [
        {
        "id": 4068,
        "pageTitle": "Another Foo",
      },
      {
        "id": 4073,
        "pageTitle": "Another Bar",
      }
  }
]
```

My query below is fetching all the parent ids and ignores child ids

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$[*].id")
FROM `my_table`;

// Returns only 4065 & 4067
```

How can I fetch and ALL the ids even for child elements or grand child etc?

Also is there a way to return the result as a one-index array, like

```
[4065, 4067, 4072, 4070, 4068, 4073]
```

or this needs to be handled programmatically eg php?

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: the MySQL JSON functions are not that mature unless you are using MySQL 8.0..Also the xpath selection is a bit wierd.. Also you seam to be working with invalid JSON..

Comment: for version 5.7

Comment: You should fix your [invalid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/?json=[{%22id%22:%204065,%22pageTitle%22:%20%22Lorem%20Ipsum%22,%22children%22:%20[{%22id%22:%204067,%22pageTitle%22:%20%22Foo%22,},{%22id%22:%204072,%22pageTitle%22:%20%22Bar%22,}},{%22id%22:%204070,%22pageTitle%22:%20%22Another%20Lorem%20Ipsum%22,%22children%22:%20[{%22id%22:%204068,%22pageTitle%22:%20%22Another%20Foo%22,},{%22id%22:%204073,%22pageTitle%22:%20%22Another%20Bar%22,}}]) first.

Comment: The json is fine, it was a mistake while I was making the example for you

Comment: @Lykos how deep can the tree go?

Comment: Its probably 1 level deep, so children may not have childern, but would prefer a flexible fix as can't be sure for all the records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7, the JSON functions are somewhat limited. However you can supply multiple paths to `JSON_EXTRACT` and so if your table is no more than 2 levels deep (i.e. grandchildren but no great-grandchildren) then this will work:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$[*].id", '$[*].children[*].id', '$[*].children[*].children[*].id')
FROM my_table
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rhw448wLVDEuaj9rYcysXY/0)

Answer (score 0):

Not a mysql answer, and if you have [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) on your system, you can use this script

```
jq '[..|.id?]' file
```

This will traverse the entire JSON data file (no matter how deep it is) and in case an `id` key is found, it prints its associated value.

[Demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/3d2jx26AXo)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example query that selects all grandchildren with the value "value_to_find" in a JSON column called "json_column":

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE json_column ->> '$**.grandchild_name' = 'value_to_find'
```

The '$**' syntax used in the above query selects all possible paths to the grandchild, regardless of the parent's name. This allows the query to find the grandchild irrespective of the parent name.